# Schema.org & Open Graph

Tags: seo, google-search, rich-snippets, open-graph-protocol, schema.org

We currently use Schema.org for our rich snippets in Google. I want to add Open Graph along with that, so other social signals will recognize our site better.

If I add OG to our existing schema, will that have any effect on our current rich snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Graph data is completely separate from structured data. There are so many sites using both the features without any issue. Here is a [link](http://moz.com/community/q/can-you-mark-up-a-page-using-schema-org-and-facebook-open-graph) from a Moz community question just like a one you asked.

Answer (score 2):

Open Graph markup is completely different from Schema.org markup usually displayed in individual `meta` tags in the site's header, like so:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

Schema.org markup is used inline with the content and is used to mark up, or describe the content itself.

Open Graph and Schema.org are two different things and have no bearing on eachother.